# database relation tables

Tags: mysql, database

Well im working on an online game project where every player will get to have a house, the project was going great until u had to organize houses thinking that i will have a limit of 10.000 players on the server.

so here are some facts:

**each player may have up to 10 houses (min 1).**
that means i need 100.000 possible houses so that no matter how full the server gets, there will always be 10 possible houses for each player.

**there will be 20 cities, each city will have 200 neighborhoods, and each neighborhood will have 25 houses**

so thats when the problem shows up, **how would the database work?**

whenever i want to see any of the 100.000 houses, it will belong to a neighborhood on a city, and i need to be able to play with that, like if i want to see house #5 of the neighborhood #123 city#8, then i should be able to get the data.

i was thinking about having one table with all 100.000 houses, and having values on that table to tell what neighborhood it is on what city, but it feels like there must be a better way. (maybe using multiple tables? i dont know)

so any help would be appreciated.

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer, because your complete requirements aren't known.

But I'd recommend that you normalize the database - 3rd normal form at minimum.  If you don't know what that is, I'd recommend learning about it ASAP.

My best guess is as follows:

1. PLAYER is one-to-many with HOUSE.  If more than one PLAYER owns the same HOUSE, then it's many-to-many.
2. CITY is one to many with NEIGHBORHOOD
3. NEIGHBORHOOD is one-to-many with HOUSE

You'll do JOINS to associate a PLAYER with cities, neighborhoods, and houses.  You should have surrogate primary keys on all tables and appropriate foreign keys.  Add UNIQUE indexes on all other candidate key combinations.

Run EXPLAIN PLAN on all your queries to make sure that they don't require TABLE SCAN and perform adequately.

10,000 players isn't a big number for a database.  You won't have any problem.

Here's what your query to select all the houses in a neighborhood might look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM HOUSE H
INNER JOIN NEIGHBORHOOD N
ON H.HOUSE_ID = N.HOUSE_ID
INNER JOIN CITY C
ON N.NEIGHBORHOOD_ID = C.NEIGHBORHOOD_ID
WHERE C.CITY_ID = 8
AND N.NEIGHBORHOOD_ID = 123
ORDER BY H.HOUSE_ID
```

Comment: well its good to know 10.000 isnt a big number, i was scared of that, i was thinking about the one to many relationships, but im not sure how it would work, lets say only for city and neighborhood, i get confused when i need to add neighborhoods to each city, if i had 2 cities, would i need 2 neighborhood tables?, an example would be nice, i feel like i can understand this easily but im just confused.

Comment: No, you just need the tables that I proposed.  One neighborhood will mean one row in the NEIGHBORHOOD table; two cities will mean two rows in the CITY table, each with a foreign key that points back to their parent city.  You add more by INSERTing more rows rather than creating more tables.  It scales much better that way, because databases have been optimized to handle lots of rows.

Comment: yeah but the thing is, then i would have to have all 4000 neighborhoods in the neihborhood table, each 200 with the fk to their city, is that right?

Comment: From your original posting. I see 20 rows in the CITY table, 20*200 rows in the NEIGHBORHOOD table, 20*200*25 rows in the HOUSE table, and 10,000 rows in the PLAYER table. That's not much to a database. You've heard of Big Data? That means terabytes. Your database is trivial.

Comment: yeah i understand how to do it that, way, i was wondering if there was a possibility to have the neighborhood table like divided in 20, and link each one of the 20 to a different city, but i guess its not as efficient as i thought, im going to work it the way you said ;D thanks a lot.

Comment: another question, how would you generate all the 10000 houses on the table?, what would be the correct sql sintax?

Comment: You populate all your tables using INSERT.  I'd write a program or a script to generate all the INSERT statements for me and then execute them all at once in MySQL.

Comment: thats what i thought, thank you a lot for your help and time :)